# I have an image and on hover of it new div will appear on it. How to have div of exactly same size

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see the site www.multia.in/mthemes which I am making.  Functionality is doing well however I need to have the hovered div equivalent to the image and should work for all the screen resolution.

How to achieve this.
Any help???

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your site and it seems that the overlay is not going to the top of each of the images.

In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fvc7L/) I made a div, gave it a background image the same size, hid the contents of the div, then on hover, displayed the contents.

CSS

```
.mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d4/Mickey_Mouse.png');
  background-size: 200px, 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .3;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;    
}
.mydiv:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```